# removing first x-characters from keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

So I have a dictionary in the like of:

```
 {'xxx.name1':'value1', 'xxx.name2':'value2',...}
```

I want to remove the first 4 characters in the keys (i.e. the characters 'xxx.').

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {k.replace("xxx.", ""): v for k, v in source.items()}
```

Comment: Or `result = {k[4:]: v for k, v in source.items()}`